Tinymce and laravel when submit form the textarea turn back to normal textarea


when submit form in livewire the editor disappers and turn back to text area

    body
<textarea class="form-control" wire:model='body' id="body">{{ old('body') }}</textarea>


@section('scripts')
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#body',
            forced_root_block: false,
            setup: function(editor) {
                editor.on('init change', function() {
                    editor.save();
                });
                editor.on('change', function(e) {
                    @this.set('body', editor.getContent());
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
@endsection

i have used wire ignore but not working

Enclosing the <textarea> managed by TinyMCE in a <div> whith the attribute wire:ignore is the right way:
<div wire:ignore>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="body">{{ old('body') }}</textarea>  
</div>

Note that I removed the wire:model because the property is managed by the line:
@this.set('body', editor.getContent());

Using a submit button to send the data to the backend it's also possible to change the javascript like:
@this.body = editor.getContent();

this way the body variable is sent to the backend only when you perform a submit, otherwise it is sent every time you add a line in the editor (more or less)
For my configuration, to test the code, I had to enclose the javascript in @script @endscript instead of @section('scripts') @endsection. Using this technique you can also replace @this with $wiresince the javascript loading is handled by Livewire:
$wire.set('body', editor.getContent());
// or
$wire.body = editor.getContent();


If all this isn't enough to fix the problem, then you also need to show how you submit the data

i have modified the code as you said but still not working
thanks for your answer.

As I was saying you should at least show how you submit the data, the information you have given is a bit limited, also look at how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
